# How to scrape data from website when the data is only accessible by pressing a button?

Tags: javascript, java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I want to scrape data from a website within my java-application. The data I want to collect is inside a html-table-element. I tried two different methods:

1. I tried to load the website with a BufferedReader into a String and collect the data from the String.
2. I tried to use Jsoup to get access to the exact html-element, but it's empty.

Turns out that the table exists, but it is empty as long as the user has not pressed a button (labled "load raw data"). I inspected the sourcecode of the webpage. When the user presses the button, a load_table()-function is called which loads the data into the table. Obviously, the URL remains the same, otherwise I could've just used the other URL where the data is already loaded into the table. **Has anyone an idea on how to scrape data from a website although it's only on the website if the user presses a button after the website is loaded?**

I'm not really a trained Javascript-coder, but I tried to look through the script which is executed after the user presses the button. It's kind of hard to understand for me but I made a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/pitifhjt) of the script with a highlighting where I think the rows are added to the table if that helps. The code for the button is:

```
<a href="#" onClick="load_table();return false;">Load raw data</a>
```

The code I use to access the html element with Jsoup would be (all the child(x) methods are called on different div-elements to go deeper into the html-document until I finally reach the table-element):

```
Jsoup.connect(url).get().body().children().get(5).child(0).child(4).child(1).child(1);
```

As I stated above, the element is empty. I hope the description of my problem is detailed enough and somebody has at least an idea of what I'm trying to say. Sorry for my clumsy expressions. Not a native speaker.

Comment: If you dive into what the JavaScript function `load_table()` is doing, chances are you'll find it's making an ajax call - if you determine the URL it's using for the ajax call, you might be able to get the data in easy to extract JSON form instead of having to scrape the html.

Answer (score 0):

if you are familiar with selenim webdriving you could use selenium to load the page and then pass to source page into beautifulSoup argument.
html =  pageSource()
you could parse the page by this method i guess